# Странная ошибка несовместимости типов в С++

Tags: php, c++, c

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь скомпилить один проект для PHP7, все ошибки исправил, и, как это часто бывает, к концу они становились все сложнее и сложнее, в итоге осталась реально одна, которую я совершенно не знаю как побороть:

> аргумент типа "int (*)(const NAME_TABLE *p1, const NAME_TABLE *p2)"
>   несовместим с параметром типа "int (__cdecl *)(const void *, const
>   void *)"

Ругается на аргумент _compare тут:

```
qsort (ptab, exports->NumberOfNames, sizeof (struct NAME_TABLE), _compare);
```

Сам _compare - это замыкание и выглядит так:

```
int _compare (const struct NAME_TABLE *p1, const struct NAME_TABLE *p2)
{
    return stricmp (p1->name, p2->name);
}
```

Что ему вообще надо?) Если третий параметр в qsort принимает только `const void *`, а мне нужно `const NAME_TABLE`, например, то как можно переназначить его тип?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что задача по C++, если код исключительно сишный?

Comment: Да вот как и писал ниже - компилил разные файлы, все и смешалось...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
int _compare (const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return stricmp (((const struct NAME_TABLE *)p1)->name, 
                    ((const struct NAME_TABLE *)p2)->name);
}
```

P.S. Только учтите - это простой C (тем более что вы даже используете именно `struct NAME_TABLE` - в С++ слово `struct` можно опустить), так что ревнители чистоты меток :) скажут, что раз у вас C++, то нужно использовать `std::sort()`...

Comment: Во дела! И правда, большое спасибо! Просто когда за целый день наприводишься кучу типов - все реально мешается)